# Make sure bypassing Vue built-in sanitization is safe here on Vue component for href

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sonarqube

I have a `.vue` file which has an anchor tag like this:

`<a class="login_class" :href="loginUrl">Use Universal Login</a>`

Sonar warns on :href:

> Make sure bypassing Vue built-in sanitization is safe here

how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

As per the Vue docs ([Vue 2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/security#Injecting-URLs), [Vue 3](https://vuejs.org/guide/best-practices/security.html#url-injection)), it's dangerous to blindly use user-provided URLs without first sanitizing them, as they can lead to arbitrary JS being executed on the page.

You should use something like `sanitize-url` ([on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@braintree/sanitize-url)) to first sanitize `loginUrl` before using it in the `:href`. On the other hand if this is a link that's programmatically generated and not user-provided (by the sound of it, `loginUrl` seems to be a static URL) then you can probably safely ignore the warnings (or just use a regular inlined string instead).

Comment: The url looks something like this:
`${window.location.origin}/login_url` And even if I use the above package, Would Sonar know now it's sanitized so it's safe or will it just treat `sanitize-url` as just another method and continue to show the warning?

Comment: @ABGR Sonar would most likely warn you regardless since it just sees a dynamic `:href`, though I can't say definitively since I've never used it myself. I assume there's a setting where you can configure what types of things it'll warn you about?

Keep in mind that `window.location.origin` counts as something that the User could modify though, so it's a good idea to sanitize it in any case

Comment: Use of `sanitize-url` doesn't do any change. Sonar still shows security hotspot warning. If it is possible then you can use @click with window.open(loginUrl,"_self").